# Saving Java Objects OR Using Xml Files

Tags: java, xml, serialization

I have related xml files with a great size (some of them ~7gb). I must use them for a research but i'm not sure about this issue:

Using this files i have to create java objects and upon them i'll work on different hypotheses. I have two choices:

**1.** I will use xml files and in run time i will create java objects and so i will work with them.

**2.** Or i will create them and will save the java objects using serialization. But it will also take time.

**3.** Or another possibility which i dont know?

I cannot be be sure which one is better than the other.

Comment: Wait, what do you need to serialize? Processing results from the data present in XML files?

Comment: That is really going to depend on what you need out of the file.  Would the entire XML file be used to instantiate one object?  If so, then serializing it is going to be a bad plan.  Is the XML file really just a bunch of "rows" of data, of which you might produce 7 billion tiny objects?  Also, probably a bad idea to serialize and store those.  Are you really going to work on them one-at-a-time?  There are a lot of questions here, the answers of which will lead to your "best" solution.

Comment: the files contain user information. i'll serialize them and also additional statistic information about them which i'll add. And i'm planning to use them in a learning and datamining process.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in the question to answer completely, but whenever I see something like "I have 7GB of data," I think "store it in a database." Especially when there are things like statistics and datamining involved, as you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: but again, the question is: accessing database and creating java objects is a better way than the saving java objects using serialization? As i said, There are dependencies between xml files, they are with a great size, it cantains users statistical information like their posts, views, preferences... And there are a lot of users. If you need any extra information to improve your answer, i can answer it.